# LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW Get row ID

Tags: winapi

How do I determine the row that is being drawn from the [LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure got via the [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fist element of the `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW` structure is a `NMCUSTOMDRAW` structure. Here, there is a `DWORD_PTR dwItemSpec` field. This is the item's "row index".

Comment: I spent 1-2 hours, searching how to get the row ID.
Thank you! 
I would never guess that the row ID is inside the drawing struct, but the subItem is in its parent struct. What an arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

The first entry of the [`NMLVCUSTOMDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774778.aspx) structure is an [`NMCUSTOMDRAW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775483.aspx). It contains a `lItemlParam` for use by the application. It holds the information stored in the [`LVITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx)'s `lParam` member when an item is created. An application can store arbitrary data in this member, including an item's row index.

Comment: The +1 I just got made me go to the 3K If it's you, many thanks :-)

Comment: @manuell Congratulations! Incidentally, I did upvote your answer. I believe, the `dwItemSpec` is in fact the row index, but the documentation didn't really give away the details it promised it would...

Comment: I think the dwItemSpec is the item ID, as to be used in the LVITEM struct for GetItem. As Items may be deleted/added, it may, or may not, be a kind of row index. I never thought of that. (+1)

Comment: `dwItemSpec` is indeed the row number / item index.

Comment: @JonathanPotter what do you call "row number"? If I insert one item at the top of the list, are all the items "renumbered"???

Comment: @manuell Yes. The item indexes reflect the order of items in the list, not the order they're added in.